# Symfony2 form not correctly representing stored property value

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a Symfony2 app with a string entity property. Depending on the values of the other properties, this string could represent the ID of another entity, a date or any random string.

My problem is the case where the property represents the ID of another entity. Since my associated form (presumably) assumes to get an entity instead of a string, the form field (in this case a dropdown of the available entities) does not properly reflect the value stored in the database, meaning that it always defaults to the first item in the list.

How can I make the form understand the the value of the property is an entity ID (in the cases which it is)?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that your database designed in a wrong way. String properties should always be strings, date properties should always be dates and relation properties should always be relations. This not only prevents confuses but also increase perfomance (because symfony generates high-perfomance join queries and uses proxy classes if appropriate properties are defined as entities).

In your case, there is a solution. You can pass any option to you form type class and dynamicly build different set of fields.

**SomeController.php:**

```
public function someAction()
{

    $propertyType = array();

    // put here your conditions to determine property type
    if (property is string)
    {
        $propertyType['type'] = 'string';
    }
    else if (property is datetime)
    {
        $propertyType['type'] = 'datetime';
    }
    else if (property is entity)
    {
        $propertyType['type'] = 'entity';
        $propertyType['class'] = '\Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Something';
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new SomeFormType(), $someData, array('propertyType' => $propertyType));
}
```

**SomeFormType.php:**

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setRequired(array(
        'propertyType',
    ));
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $array = array('required' => true, 'label' => 'Your label');
    if ($options['propertyType']['type'] == 'entity'
        $array['class'] = $options['propertyType']['class']

    $builder
        ->add('title', $options['propertyType']['type'], $array)
    ;
}
```